# Relativistic heat equation and form of "relativistic kinetic energy"

Tags: special-relativity, energy

I'm reading a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05030) on a proposed form for the relativistic heat equation derived by optimal transport from a relativistic cost function. In particular, the paper they reference shows how the heat equation follows from the usual kinetic energy $E_\mathrm{kin}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and how using a "cost function [with] obvious geometric and relativistic flavour", aka $$K(v)=mc^2\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}\right),$$
yields a relativistic heat equation. This expression is treated like a relativistic kinetic energy of some type, but it does not align with any form of relativistic kinetic energy I know. Is there some interpretation of this energy I'm unaware of, or is it a misnomer to call it relativistic just because it has some "relativity"-looking limits for $v\to0$ and $v\to c$?

Comment: Couldn't see any reference to the Lorentz Transform, or Minkowski space.  Smells of _gamma slinging_ to me.

Comment: All these models of relativistic heat conduction are just phenomenological approaches not rooted in relativistic kinetic theory, so they can be derived in the most bizarre ways. This does not provide a physical interpretation or derivation. Relativistic heat conduction that is both stable and causal was derived from kinetic theory long ago, see eg. the review https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2105.15184

Comment: @Quillo Oh very interesting, I didn't know about that one. Thanks for the paper!

Comment: @m4r35n357 You're right, it's more or less just mathematics without connection to physics. And *gamma slinging* is a nice phrase :D

Comment: Thank you - it was "designed" to be descriptive, vaguely contemptuous, and easy to say ;)